# How to set upload limit in sharepoint 2010 for site collection?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, site-collection, file-upload

I can set upload limit for web application in SharePoint 2010. But cannot do it for specific site collection?

Answer (score 1):

OOTB there is no way to control this property at site collection level. You can set it at Web Application level but not for site collection.

as a workaround, you need to write some kind of custom code to do it at site collection level. [check this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c443531-f9e5-4e63-8e01-91d0a4b8441e/setting-maximum-upload-size-for-document-library-for-sub-site-level?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

another workaround is, if there are multiple site collections which need higher upload limit, you can think about creating a new webapp and move all site collection their. but this has some pros and cons.